# Can't get a traditional google map and complementing streetview to change based on div/button clicks

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I am trying to set up two separate divs where one is showing a traditional google map and one is showing the streetview of that location next to it. Then I am trying to change these locations by clicking a button so that I can add several locations to showcase. Having difficulties however. I imagine I can put the latitudes and longitudes in a separate document, but how do I load them into the different buttons? I can't seem to make even one work. Appreciate any help or nudges in the right direction. Thanks!

```
<script>
function initialize() {
var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(59.92883,10.75943);

document.getElementById('changeValues').onclick = function(coords) {
coords = this.coords;

var mapOptions = {
       center: coords,
       zoom: 16,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(
       document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var panoramaOptions = {
       position: coords,
       pov: {
         heading: 80,
         pitch: 10
            }
   };

var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'),panoramaOptions);
map.setStreetView(panorama);
       }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
        <div id="pano" style="position:absolute; left:510px; top: 8px; width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
        <div id="meny"><input type="button" value="changeValues" id="changeValues" /></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```